# Is there any downside in setting a form to multipart in HTML?

Tags: html, forms, multipart

I'm dynamically building forms and at the time I output the form tag I'm not sure if the form will or will not have a file field. Is there any downside to always making these forms multipart? Why aren't we making all forms everywhere multipart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a downside. Maybe the text/plain can be a little bit lighter on the transaction but I don't think is considerable. But for markup reasons, to keep your code clean I would only use the multipart when you're actually uploading a file.

#### EDIT

I just did the test using a simple [form](http://jsfiddle.net/kmendes/M4NnT/) and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2) and the results are:

```
-text/plain: 1,552 bytes sent
-mulipart/form-data: 1,644 bytes sent
```

Text/plain is a very little bit lighter in this case.

Now if you have a bigger [form](http://jsfiddle.net/kmendes/M4NnT/1/) the results are:

```
-text/plain: 1,772 bytes sent
-mulipart/form-data: 2,837 bytes sent
```

Apparently the difference will be higher as the size of the form increases.

I can't say that this is a enough difference if making everything a multipart will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible enctype options (as stated on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)):

1. **text/plain** Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded.
2. **multipart/form-data** No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control.
3. **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** This is the default enctype. All characters are encoded before sent (spaces are converted to "+" symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values)

Other then that, there are no 'setbacks', it just determines in which way the form data will be sent to the server.